# What changed in angularjs from 1.4.8 that this routing is not working anymore?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to learn about AngularJS routing, and got this code to study. It is working on version 1.4.8 but when I updated to 1.6.x stop working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- DOESN'T WORK -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- WORKS -->
<!-- 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
-->

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I already checked the changelogs and found nothing.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52. Note that even in 1.4.x, it should be #/red, not #red.

Comment: Why the -1? It is a simple, concise and honest question, provided with the simplest possible code ever, and I don't know angularjs to find that answer by myself. As I stated, I am trying to learn about it. 
It seems people are too arrogant these days.

Comment: Thank you, @JBNizet. It works on this example. But still doesn't work on my real code. I will research a little bit more.

Comment: What works/doesn't work? Have you added the exclamation mark? Or have you reconfigured the location provider?

Comment: Now it seems to be related with the order of my scripts. Not related with the "!" prefix. I am trying to use John Papa's Style Guide, but routes script is being called before module script.

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but you can see the changelog for angular on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thank you @JoelCDoyle, the "!" that JBNizet wrote about worked for me.